# Unable to find TargetElement of a Storyboard

Tags: c#, xaml, storyboard, windows-store-apps

In my Windows 8.1 Store app I am trying to move 2 UI elements horizontally by defining translate transforms for them and then animating the transforms. Below is the simplified XAML for my scenario:

**MyUserControl.Xaml**

```
    <UserControl
        x:Class="AnimTest.UserControls.MyUserControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Grid Background="BlueViolet"/>
    </UserControl>
```

**MainPage.Xaml**

```
    <Page
        x:Class="AnimTest.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:userControls="using:AnimTest.UserControls">

        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="MoveContentGrid">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentGridTransform"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                     By="250"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                     EnableDependentAnimation="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="MoveMyUserControl">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyUserControlTransform"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                     By="250"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                     EnableDependentAnimation="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="Blue">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentGridTransform" />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
            </Grid>

            <userControls:MyUserControl Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0">
                <userControls:MyUserControl.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="MyUserControlTransform" X="-250" />
                </userControls:MyUserControl.RenderTransform>
            </userControls:MyUserControl>

            <Button Content="Animate" Grid.Row="1" Click="AnimateButton_OnClick"/>
        </Grid>
    </Page>
```

**MainPage.Xaml.cs**

```
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

    namespace AnimTest
    {
        public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
        {
            public MainPage()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void AnimateButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                MoveContentGrid.Begin();
                MoveMyUserControl.Begin();
            }
        }
    }
```

when I click on the Animate button, I get the following exception:

> System.Exception: No installed components were detected.
>
> Cannot resolve TargetName MyUserControlTransform.    at
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard.Begin()    at
>   AnimTest.MainPage.AnimateButton_OnClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs
>   e)

But if I comment out *MoveMyUserControl.Begin();* from the code behind, then the call to *MoveContentGrid.Begin();* works just fine and that storyboard begins its animation.

Any idea why the second call causes this exception and how to get this to work?

Comment: It can't find MyUserControlTransform because its not a direct descendant of the grid. I'm not sure, but try giving your usercontrol a name with x:Key and reference it by the full path (MyControlName.MyUserControlTransform) in the animation.

Comment: @ron-beyer Can't define x:Key on my control since it is neither a resource nor a dictionary element. But I did place the user control inside another Grid and had my translate transform/storyboard applied to this containing Grid and that solves my issue. But to be that approach is a bit ugly. Am still hoping to find a way to tell the storyboard to directly target the user control if possible.